# AWS Lambda - Cognito sign up/log in on a node.js lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I am trying to run AWS Cognito Identity on AWS Lambda, trying to handle user sign up in a function, rather than putting all that logic in the view.

Firstly, is this at all possible?

Here's what I've done:

1 Wrote a Lambda function, using some of the example code AWS published in their docs.

2. installed the 'amazon-cognito-identity-js' node packages.
3. Zipped it all up and published it to Lambda

Here is the first few lines of my function:

```
const AWSCognito = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js');
const userPoolId = '<region>-blah';
const clientId = 'blah';

AWSCognito.config.region = '<region>';

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
```

I am getting the following error though:

```
{
    "errorMessage": "Cannot find module '/var/task/index'",
    "errorType": "Error",
    "stackTrace": [
        "Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)",
        "Module.require (module.js:497:17)",
        "require (internal/module.js:20:19)"
    ]
}
```

I've looked around online and everything I've found says that it can be because I'm zipping it up wrong. I've checker, and the only thing in the .zip file is the `node_modules` folder and my ''userSignUp.js`` file.

Can anyone spot something I'm missing here, or is it simply not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the .js file with your code called "index.js" or something else?

If it is not called index.js, you will get that error if you zipped it up correctly.

Check your function config for the "Handler" parameter. By default it should be "index.handler". Say your file is called xyz.js, then you should change the handler to be "xyz.handler".